First-passage time inside boundary: different or same?
System description
I want to ask question about first-passage time (FPT) in 1D.
First of all, assume Brownian dynamics following
$$
\dot{x}=\sqrt{2D}\xi(t),\qquad\langle\xi(t)\xi(t^{'})\rangle=\delta(t-t^{'})
$$
where $x$ is position, $D$ is diffusion coefficient and $\xi(t)$ is white Gaussian noise.
Here, reflecting boundary is at $x=0$, absorbing boundary is at $x=L$, and I tried to derive FPT for reaching $M$, starting from $x_0$.
(For system, please refer to the link above.)
My question is, when I discard $x=L$ boundary (i.e. unbounded system), is FPT same as before?
In simple thinking, since only $x<M$ trajectories are concerned, they should be same.
But I worried whether change of sample space (trajectory space) can change it significantly; if so, is there any relation between those two?
